# How do I run a executable .sh file on a remote server from local in its remote-existed path?

Tags: ssh

update:

Sorry it seems the command is executed on remote but just not in the path of where `script.sh` exists.

So I modified the question title from

*How do I run a executable .sh file on a remote server from local machine?*

to

*How do I run a executable .sh file on a remote server from local in its remote-existed path?*

---

I created a shell script `my_script.sh` on my remote server "111.111.111.111". It works with the server's file system and do some job that I want.

Then I want to run the command from local terminal like:

`ssh -p 22 user@111.111.111.111 "~/user/path/my_script.sh"`

But I noticed that the shell is executed at the `~/user/` path not the `~/user/path/`.

What should I do to make sure the shell script performed exactly as I type `my_script.sh` in the remote terminal in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh user@111.111.111.111 'cd ~/user/path && ./my_script.sh'`

Comment: thanks, but what is the difference between your answer and `cd ~/user/path && ./my_script.sh`? All the same?

Comment: The difference between `;` and `&&` as command separators is that if you use `&&`, the whole command line will abort if the first one fails. That's probably better, in this case; you might have a `my_script.sh` in the home directory, which could be run by accident. Edited.